# Vue cant add method in child component

Tags: vue.js, parent

I try send data from child to parent:
In child:

```
<input type="checkbox" @click="changeCheckbox">

changeCheckbox(e){
    this.$emit("change", e);
}
```

In parent I have:

```
<AddElement @change="saveCheckbox"></AddElement>
```

and method in parent:

```
saveCheckbox(e){
  console.log(e)
},
```

But this is not work so, I change:

```
method: {
    changeCheckbox(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Still I have this same error:

> Property or method "changeCheckbox" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Comment: methods, plural. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Comment: I want to kill myself, I looked at it for 30 minutes and did not see it, Thanks ;)